# Is it possible to refresh a CollectionViewSource too often? Having some strange issues occur

Tags: wpf

I've got these ListViews bound to a couple of CollectionViewSources.  Those are in turn bound to ObservableCollection lists which have plenty of data that updates quite often (it monitors a 32 player game server and displays player metadata and events).  I wouldn't ever call Refresh() on the view if it weren't for the apparent necessity to make sure it is continually sorted by Score and to ensure added/removed players are updated on the UI.

Now the issue I've run into is that too many refreshes to the Views will cause them to lose the ability to open a context menu.  You can right-click all you want but it will not appear until you destroy the form and re-instantiate it (an unacceptable workaround).

Has anybody ever seen this behavior, and know how to get around it? Initially I was Refreshing as often as it felt it needed to -- this caused the issue almost immediately.  I reduced these Refreshes to every 5 seconds and now it happens but not quite as often.

Answer (score 0):

We have had several problems with the CollectionViewSource. It causes lots of performance issues after openening the same window for appr. 5 times. It might be because we were using an [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com) collection as items source, but I will never use the CollectionViewSource again.

Now, I wouldn't refresh the view manually. Your ObservableCollection is responsible for updating the data. Try removing the CollectionViewSource for now (so you will lose the sorting ability), and see if the problem still occurs. If it disappears, you will need another way to sort your collection.